# Add authentication to Git repository

Tags: git, authentication, repository, credentials

This may be very simple feature but unfortunately I am not able to find it anywhere which even makes me thing, if such a feature exists.

Can we add authentication to a repo just like in GitHub? I want to require a username and password before cloning/pushing code.

Comment: clone https, it will ask you for credentials everytime you push/pull

Comment: how do i configure users?

Comment: You don't configure users, remote repository owner grants access to other users for a private project (This is done via git host providers ex github , gitlab ).

Comment: Setting up SSH authentication is not difficult and avoids having to manage passwords.  Is username/password a requirement?

Comment: Yes. say I dont want one team to clone other team project